# Why Python-Nmap cannot scan Localhost but Socket can do it?

Tags: python, sockets, nmap

This is my script and my question is Why Socket scan the Localhost but Nmap can't?

```
import nmap
import optparse
import socket

tgtHost = "127.0.0.1"
tgtPort = 80

nmScan = nmap.PortScanner()
try:
    result = nmScan.scan(tgtHost, str(tgtPort))
    nmScan.scan(tgtHost, tgtPort)
    state=nmScan[tgtHost]['tcp'][int(tgtPort)]['state']
    print(" [*] " + tgtHost + " tcp/"+tgtPort +" "+state)
except:
    print(f"{tgtHost} is unreachable.")

try:
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.settimeout(0.5)
        s.connect((tgtHost, tgtPort))
        print(f"Port {tgtPort} is open on {tgtHost}.")

except:
    print(f"{tgtHost} is unreachable.")
```

This is the result.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this method to check if a port is open or closed :

```
import nmap

tgtHost = "127.0.0.1"
tgtPort = 80

nmScan = nmap.PortScanner()

try:
    result = nmScan.scan(tgtHost, str(tgtPort))
    state = result['scan'][tgtHost]['tcp'][tgtPort]['state']
    print(f"[*] {tgtHost} tcp/{tgtPort} {state}")
except:
    print(f"{tgtHost} is unreachable.")
```

Output:

```
[*] 127.0.0.1 tcp/80 closed
```

Another example:

[image: Example of output]

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are doing a ping scan with nmap and ping is closed.

Use equivalent of `-Pn` switch (or `-P0`).

Also, check if result of `s.connect()` is actually a valid connection.